# Can't run, remove or reinstall gnome-tweak-tool

Tags: apt, package-management, gnome-tweak-tool

When I try to run:

```
$ gnome-tweak-tool 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool", line 26, in <module>
    import gtweak
ImportError: No module named 'gtweak'
```

Then when I try to remove I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-tweak-tool
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-tweak-tool*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,005 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package gnome-tweak-tool (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-tweak-tool
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when I try to reinstall

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-tweak-tool is already the newest version (3.20.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/170 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package gnome-tweak-tool (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-tweak-tool
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Since I wanted to install and run other packages I did this:

```
$ sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Located the gnome-tweak package, and removed the whole block of information about it and saved the file.

I made some changes in python early to install some software. I think I made python3 default but I don't remember exactly. I have not looked into tweak tool for some time. Now I need help to get it working. What should I do?

Result of reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-tweak-tool
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/170 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,005 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-tweak-tool.
(Reading database ... 512559 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-tweak-tool_3.20.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-tweak-tool (3.20.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.8.0-46.49) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:i386 (4.8.0-46.49) ...
Setting up gnome-tweak-tool (3.20.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package gnome-tweak-tool (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+16.10.20160929-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up linux-tools-common (4.8.0-46.49) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (231-9ubuntu3) ...
Setting up lightdm (1.19.5-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.19.5-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic (4.8.0-46.49) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
W: plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so) missing, skipping that theme.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-44-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Setting up linux-headers-4.8.0-46 (4.8.0-46.49) ...
Setting up linux-tools-4.8.0-46 (4.8.0-46.49) ...
Setting up linux-tools-4.8.0-46-generic (4.8.0-46.49) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.8.0-46-generic (4.8.0-46.49) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic (4.8.0-46.49) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
W: plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so) missing, skipping that theme.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-44-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.8.0.46.58) ...
Setting up linux-tools-virtual (4.8.0.46.58) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.8.0.46.58) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.8.0.46.58) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-tweak-tool
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
athul@black-box:~$ gnome-tweak-tool 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool", line 26, in <module>
    import gtweak
ImportError: No module named 'gtweak'
```

**Python Output**

```
athul@black-box:~$ python --version
Python 3.5.2+
athul@black-box:~$ readlink -f "$(which python)"
/usr/bin/python3.5
athul@black-box:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
athul@black-box:~$ readlink "$(which python)"
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: I think that the <code>gtweak</code> module that the error message describes is not Python 3 compatible, thus resulting in a missing module error. If you made Python 3 the system default, then you need to undo whatever you did in order to let Gnome Tweak Tool run properly.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall already? -> `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster I want to install gnome-tweak-tool back.I did copy pasted everything needed i believe.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yes i tried but no success same error

Comment: @VinayakG. I too thought so but i need to be sure and i don't remember exactly what all i did.

Comment: `apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` is ***not*** the same as `apt-get install --reinstall gnome-tweak-tool`. Please try to run the ***exact*** command that CelticWarrior suggested! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It is showing same error i did it early itself i am updating that too to now.

Comment: @athul Vinayak is right: You need to set Python2 as the system default. (You can tell the error is from Python3 by the quotes around the module name.)

Comment: Good point! What's the output of `python --version` and `readlink -f "$(which python)"`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I updated those too. But pip need python 3 instead of 2 which made me do so.

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem right there. A ton of system tools rely on `/usr/bin/python` referring to Python 2.7 since that's what Python itself requires for a standardized runtime environment. Pip runs with both Python 2 (package `python-pip`) and Python 3 (package `python3-pip`).

Comment: How did you get `python` to refer to Python 3? What's the output of `which python`, `readlink "$(which python)"` and `readlink -f "$(which python)"`? (Note that there is no `?` at the end of the last command. The question mark is the correct English punctuation to terminate the question that contains said command.)

Comment: @DavidFoerster firstly sorry for my dump mistake over copy pasting.I didn't know the command. [what i did to make python refer to python3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04)It was not to install pip but to install lamp with  python3. I didnt remember exactly early as i did faced issues when python 2.7 was default. But i didn't know how to change then and this page helped.Now i will revert back to 2.7 .

Comment: The first part of that article (making Python 3 the default) is superfluous and harmful bollocks. The remaining steps would work just as well without the first step but with minor adjustments.

Comment: @David can you help with exact step to revert back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part (making Python 3 the default) of the article "[How To Set Up an Apache, MySQL, and Python (LAMP) Server Without Frameworks on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04)" is superfluous and harmful bollocks because a ton of system tools rely on `/usr/bin/python` referring to Python 2.7 since that's what Python itself requires for a standardized runtime environment.

You can revert that step with either of the two:

- Revert the symbolic link to its previous target:

  ```
  sudo ln -sf python2 /usr/bin/python
  ```
- Reinstall the `python-minimal` package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall python-minimal
  ```

---

Additionally you can edit the first line of the Python script of step 5 to read

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

and the Python-on-Apache setup should still work like before.

Comment: It worked. But had to reinstall the python when i was upgrading to ubuntu 17. But for some reason system crashed. And now stuck with my next question.

Comment: I'm not sure how your question is related to the upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 since you didn't mention it. If you have a new or follow-up question could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask)? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Beware that Ubuntu 17.04 is only going to be released officially on the 13th ([according to schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseSchedule)) and questions related to it are likely going to be off topic until then. Thanks.

Comment: I made it as new question.And i solved it myself